# RGBD-SLAM and STEREO

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

How to use rgbd-slam with two cameras?
I have read http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam
I run rgbd-slam from command line
"roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch"
and it said: "cannot find kinect device".
What should I put into command line in order to say rgbdslam
reads frames(images) from two cameras, not from kinect device?
Did anyone get success with it?

Also, I have tried to to use bagfiles instead of kinect device to get pre-saved frames(images), however did not get any success.
Does anyone have example of using bagfiles?

My enviroment:
Ubuntu 11.10
ROS electric
2 cameras

Thanks a lot,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41266/rgbd-slam-and-stereo/) by [dalspenguin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3019/dalspenguin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to compute a pointcloud from your stereo vision data, then have rgbdslam listen to the 2d image and the cloud. Set the parameters "wide_topic" and "wide_cloud_topic" to listen to the topics where the respective data is published.

The cloud must be dense, i.e. stored in a 2D grid where each point corresponds to one pixel and vice versa.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0